# Can the definition of an holonomic basis be done point by point?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

Can the definition of an holonomic basis be done point by point?

Namely, instead of taking the commutator of two vector fields (local basis) $[e_i,e_j]=0$, is it equivalent to state that the commutator of two vectors must vanish at every point of the manifold $[e^p_i,e^p_j]=0$ (where $\{e^p_i\}$ is an ordered basis of the tangent space $T_pM$)?

Comment: What is $[e_i^p, e_j^p]$?

Comment: Commutator of basis vectors of $T_p M$.

Comment: And how should that be defined?